# Convertir Binario a Decimal en netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

como convierto de binario a decimal mediante la recursividad amigos, estoy implementando mi código de esta manera, pero de aquí me quedé:

```
Public class binarioDecimal{
public int binarioADecimal(int v[], int n){
  if(n<0){
    return 0;
  }else{
    return binarioDecimal(binario, n-1);
  }
}
```

Comment: no se que intentas hacer, en el código que pones la variable `v[]` no es usada y tampoco describe que contiene el arreglo, para  que es la variable `n`, antes de escribir el código, usted tiene claro como se convierte " a mano" un binario a decimal?

Comment: Por qué no pruebas antes a hacer una funcion que convierta de binario a decimal en secuencial? Una vez la tengas y ya tengas claro como funciona te será más facil hacerlo de forma recursiva.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código prácticamente no dice nada, de hecho esta completamente mal ya que en ningún momento declaras la variable "binario" que envías en el 2do return y también llamas a un constructor que no ha sido declarado.

Te dejo una opción que es mas parecida a lo que intentaste hacer

```
public class BinaryToDecimal {
  // variable global que contendra el valor del decimal
  private int decimalValue = 0;
  //recibe como parametros el numero binario almacenado en un array y el 
  indice con el que trabajara
  public int convertBinaryToDecimal( int[] binaryValue, int index ) {
  //comprueba que el indice no sea menor que 0
  if(index >= 0) {
    //comprueba que el valor del binario sea 1 en la posicion del indice
    if(binaryValue[index] == 1) {
      // suma el valor del binario correspondiente al indice y lo guarda en decimalValue
      // ten en cuenta que el valor de un digito binario depende de la posicion en la que este en el arreglo
      // 
      // Ejemplo
      // 
      // indice del arreglo        0           2          3           4           5           6            7
      // valor del binario        2^6         2^5        2^4         2^3         2^2         2^1          2^0
      // 
      // Nota que se le resta 1 al numero de elementos del arreglo ya que un array comienza desde la posicion 0
      //
      decimalValue = (int) (decimalValue + (Math.pow(2, ( (binaryValue.length-1) - index ))));
      //Recursividad restandole 1 al indice para trabajar con el indice anterior
      convertBinaryToDecimal(binaryValue, index-1);
    }
    //en caso de que el valor del binario sea 0 en la posicion del indice no hace falta hacer ninguna operacion
    else{
    //Recursividad restandole 1 al indice para trabajar con el indice anterior
      convertBinaryToDecimal(binaryValue, index-1);
    }
  }
  //devuelve el valor del binario en Decimal
  return decimalValue;
  }
}
```

Para llamarlo solo necesitas pasar el binario contenido en un arreglo y el indice de la ultima posición del arreglo por ejemplo

```
public class Principal {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int binary [] = {1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1};
    BinaryToDecimal btd = new BinaryToDecimal();
    int valueDecimal = btd.convertBinaryToDecimal(binary, binary.length-1);
    System.out.println("el valor del binario en decimal es: "+ valueDecimal);
  }
}
```

Comment: Si cierto amigo, Gracias por el aporte, de hecho si me equivoqué, pero gracias amigo